# Load pptx which contains Images in Android

Tags: android, powerpoint

I have added the pptViewer library in my project from https://github.com/itsrts/pptviewer-android. But ppt or pptx which contains only images does not get open.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Aspose.Slides for Android via Java](https://products.aspose.com/slides/android-java) or [Aspose.Slides Cloud](https://products.aspose.cloud/slides/).